# Javascript throttle implementation is not delaying

Tags: javascript, html

this is probably a simple mistake. I'm trying to implement a throttle function (Credit to our man webdevsimplified for quality content: https://blog.webdevsimplified.com/2022-03/debounce-vs-throttle/).

My throttle implementation is not working and I am not sure why. How can I get the throttle working?

```js
function printHi() {
    console.log("Hi");
}

function throttle(cb, delay = 1000) {
    let shouldWait = false
    let waitingArgs
    const timeoutFunc = () => {
        if (waitingArgs == null) {
            shouldWait = false
        } else {
            cb(...waitingArgs)
            waitingArgs = null
            setTimeout(timeoutFunc, delay)
        }
    }

    return (...args) => {
        console.log("should wait?", shouldWait);

        if (shouldWait) {
// It never goes in here...?
            waitingArgs = args
            return
        }

        cb(...args)
        shouldWait = true
        setTimeout(timeoutFunc, delay)
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="(function () {
    throttle(printHi)();
})()">Click me</button>
```

Consecutive button clicks print to the console:

```
should wait? false
Hi
should wait? false
Hi
should wait? false
Hi
```

`shouldWait` is never printed `true`, even though it should...

Comment: This API is meant to be used like this: `const throttledFunction = throttle(printHi);`. Then calling `throttledFunction()` several times will produce the expected output. The function returned in `throttle` [closes over](/a/111111/4642212) `shouldWait`. If you just keep calling `throttle` itself all the time, it will just create a new closure, thus defeating the purpose of this API.

Comment: @SebastianSimon oh yeah, this might have been a better solution than my answer.

Comment: Cheers @SebastianSimon, so what I was erroneously doing was creating a 'new' version of `throttle` at each time. I needed a reference to it instead (i.e. `throttledFunction`). This closure stuff is confusing! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original implementation didn't work because `shouldWait` and `waitingArgs` were scoped to the function, so every function run had a fresh set of these variables with `shouldWait = false`.

You might have made this mistake due to the scope differences between `var` and `let`, the former was globally scoped if used this way.

Here is my solution, which simply moved the 2 variables out of the function.

```js
function printHi() {
    console.log("Hi");
}

let shouldWait = false
let waitingArgs
function throttle(cb, delay = 1000) {
    const timeoutFunc = () => {
        if (waitingArgs == null) {
            shouldWait = false
        } else {
            cb(...waitingArgs)
            waitingArgs = null
            setTimeout(timeoutFunc, delay)
        }
    }

    return (...args) => {
        console.log("should wait?", shouldWait);

        if (shouldWait) {
// It never goes in here...?
            waitingArgs = args
            return
        }

        cb(...args)
        shouldWait = true
        setTimeout(timeoutFunc, delay)
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <button onclick="(function () {
        throttle(printHi)();
    })()">Click me</button>
</body>
```